# Spring Boot Hibernate - Override Entity in DB based on Unique key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

Just to clarify: Im working with the Confluence API and im getting some data, so now in case i get 2x the same data from the same page, i would love to "override" the entity in the DB, my database table got a "ID" which i get from the API(it is UNIQUE) so i marked it in my DB as:

```
page_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
```

for the first time it work, after that i get an error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Duplicate entry '10817891' for key 'page_id'
```

obv. becouse its not overriding the entity in the DB, my question here is, how would i do that?
my Entity ID Key in the java.class looks like this:

```
@Column(name = "page_id", unique = true)
private String pageId;
```

i thought if the "Column" is marked as "unique" it will override it when i try to save it,

for saving i use the CRUDRepository which is super handy

Comment: Database Unique will only limit you not to insert two data with the same value, but it won't update the existing one as you thought. You will have to handle that exception or first check with the database if that value exists and if exists update the row.

Comment: if u will eliminate `UNIQUE` constraint from your db hibernate will most likely merge entries the way you want via `save()` / `saveAll()`